# Add Multiple Jssor instances I loose responsive slideshow

Tags: jssor

If I follow the recommendations of this post:

[How can I add multiple jssor instances on the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713441/how-can-i-add-multiple-jssor-instances-on-the-same-page)

I lose the responsive ability of my slideshow. This happens when the second instance is instantiated. Maybe this has something to do with the ScaleSlider function?

To clarify here is a sample of code I'm using:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var options_vertical_slider = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $PlayOrientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 2,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_vertical_slider = new $JssorSlider$("container_vertical_slider", options_vertical_slider);
        var options_photo_slider = {
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)
            $UISearchMode: 0,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).

            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always

                $Loop: 2,                                       //[Optional] Enable loop(circular) of carousel or not, 0: stop, 1: loop, 2 rewind, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 3,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 3,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each thumbnail in pixel, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 6,                              //[Optional] Number of pieces to display, default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 204,                          //[Optional] The offset position to park thumbnail,

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                    $Steps: 6                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                }
            }
        };

        var jssor_photo_slider = new $JssorSlider$("slider_photo_container", options_photo_slider);            



        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_vertical_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_vertical_slider.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 480));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }

        //Scale slider immediately
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end            
    });
```

When jssor_photo_slider is instantiated I lose responsive scaling for the contents within container_vertical_slider.

Answer (score 1):

A second responsive scale function solves the problem. I guess you need to add one for each slider on a page:

```
        function ScaleSlider2() {
            var parentWidth = jssor_photo_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_photo_slider.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth, 770));

            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider2();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider2);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider2);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider2);
        //responsive code end
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second slider, please replace all 'slider1' with 'slider2'.

Please check out your code (both html and javascript).

The the following example responsive codes for the second slider.

```
    //responsive code begin
    //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales
    //while window resizes
    function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = $('#slider2_container').parent().width();
        if (parentWidth) {
            jssor_slider2.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
    }
    //Scale slider after document ready
    ScaleSlider();

    //Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
    //responsive code end
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm doing but I loose responsive. I added more code details